# Override Doctrine Mappgins in the Child Bundle

Tags: php, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there a way to override Doctrine mappings for some entity in the child bundle.

I have parent entity which is in third party bundle, it has softdeleatable extension enabled, I would like to disable that.

So, in third party bundle there is:

`<gedmo:soft-deleteable field-name="deletedAt" />`

Is there a way to override/disable that in my child bundle without changing third party code and still keep parent entity functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions could be override entity metaclass mapping via `EventListener`.

See an example here: [Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 overriding entity configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872523/symfony-2-doctrine-2-overriding-entity-configuration/31603942#answer-31603942)

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing this. Thanks for answering, forgot to share my solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to extend the parent entity and to write the whole mapping yourself. Using external mapping — not annotations — is the way.

Comment: But since parent bundle is already included, it parses parent bundle mappings as well, so it throws `Duplicate definition of column ...` errors.