# Symfony 2 + Doctrine 2 overriding entity configuration

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a case where I need to **reuse common doctrine entities** across multiple applications (that reside within the same project). These applications are merely instances of information system used by corresponding institutions.

I've isolated all entities and repositories into separate bundle and that worked like a charm so far. **Here's the catch:** I have received a requirement that only some of these instances need to support some other features. Modification would include adding new attributed/relations to some of entities.

Here is the brief example:

We have a university which has number of faculty units (instances, that is). Information system was built to support only **bachelor** studies program but a month ago we received requirement to support **specialization** and **master** studies as well. They want to handle all the them thought the same application instance. **This applies only to some of these instances**.

**The question:** Is there any way to "override" affected entities while keeping functionality of original ones?   Can I override entity configuration (YAML or annotation, not important), at all? I would really like to keep the code base and not to copy all the entities/repositories to another package...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/override.html#entities-entity-mapping) means. Looks like it is possible but not documented yet. I don't whether the documentation or the code is in progress.

[In this issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/issues/978), stof suggests it is not possible at all.

I think you should use SCM branches for this.

Comment: That's too bad :( Seems like it really won't be supported :-/

Comment: Apart from that, it seems that mapped superclasses is the closest thing I will get to extending the model. Still there are number of limitations to this....

Comment: Using SCM branches is an option but my original thought was to have all the code in `master` branch. Somehow it seemed easier to manage all the code that way. Since the requirement I mentioned in my post was resolved via copy/pasting code (I know, big frekin' NO) I look forward to refactoring phase we'll be having in a month or so when I will suggest you idea :) I will wait a day or two for more potential suggestions but as far as it goes, points go to you ;)

Comment: I know that it was a long time ago but I just wanted to thank you again for pointing me into right direction. We began a whole new refactoring of application and SCM branching as you suggested has proved to be very neat indeed :)

Answer (score 5):

You can override classes metadata on entities loading by catching an event.

### EventListener

```
<?php

namespace Lol\RandomBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LoadClassMetadataEventArgs;

class ClassMetadataListener
{
    /**
     * Run when Doctrine ORM metadata is loaded.
     *
     * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
     */
    public function loadClassMetadata(LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        $classMetadata = $eventArgs->getClassMetadata();

        // Override User class to flag MappedSuperclass.
        if ('AnotherLol\AnotherRandomBundle\Entity\User' === $classMetadata->name) {
            // Do whatever you want...
            $classMetadata->isMappedSuperclass = true;
        }
    }
}
```

### Services configuration

```
services:
    lol.random.listener.class_metadata:
        class: Lol\RandomBundle\EventListener\ClassMetadataListener
        tags:
            -  { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: loadClassMetadata }
```

Comment: Given that the question is almost 3 years old, and team's decision is almost 2 years old, this can only be useful for some future projects. But thanks for the idea :)

Comment: I hope someone with similar problem will find this solution useful.

Answer (score 2):

Sympatch provides tools to override any code part of your Symfony2 project, including entities, without destroying the code base. See https://github.com/DHorchler/SympatchBundle.